# How to disable Nginx index directory to only allow MaxCDN / NetDNA CDN?

Tags: nginx, cdn, directory-structure

I have a very large CDN purge server. It is structured like so

```
site.com/
site.com/assets/
site.com/assets/products/3424/imgs/large.jpg
site.com/assets/products/3424/imgs/med.jpg
site.com/assets/products/3424/imgs/small.jpg
site.com/assets/products/3424/xml/xml.xml
site.com/assets/products/3424/swf/swfvideo.jpg
site.com/assets/products/3424/html5/video.ogg
site.com/assets/products/3424/mp3/mp3.jpg
```

and so on.. there are large directories. I was wondering if I can disable ALL access to the directory listings /assets/, /products/, /3424/ - so basically the only people that can see the directories are the CDN purge bot. I want the CDN to be able to cache all the index folders and directories. Users would see forbidden on the directory but obviously they can see files..

Comment: There is a nginx module named  AutoIndex , you could read about it here - http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpAutoindexModule

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this can be accomplished by simply adding lines similar to this in the virtual server's config file:

```
server {
  listen 80; # look familiar?

  ...

  # something similar to this
  if ($remote_addr != cdnIP) {
    location /assets {
      deny  all;
    }
  }
}
```

Check out the [configuration wiki](http://wiki.nginx.org/Configuration) on nginx's site for more about syntax and working with the config files to get them just how you want them.

Comment: what if they are not just an IP.. it is 44.444.33.** or package.bucketbot.netdna.com - I think they use different pull zone bots?

Comment: Looks like then you could use something like $http_host instead of $remote_addr. Check out the [available variables](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#Variables) you can manipulate in nginx configs